# How to communicate between modules using Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, module, multi-module

I have a scenario of navigating between Module(s).

Say I have two modules, A and B. In **Module A**'s Gradle file I have imported the **Module B**. Now I want to call a function in **Module A** from **Module B**. How can it be done via an interface or another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to call interface from module A in be, then

```
dependencies {

    implementation(project(":ModuleA"))
```

need to be in Module B not module A

Also, you need to clear Module B from Module A since Module A don't need to know about Module B.

#### Example case

Let’s assume Module A is the domain.
Module B is the data layer.

The data layer knows about the domain, but the domain doesn't need to know about the data layer.

You can refer to this project for a sample:

[Clean Architecture, Modularization and Unit Testing](https://github.com/muryno/CleanArchitecture_Modularization/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

Note:

Having a circular dependency between two modules,
Module A depending on Module B and Module B depending on Module A, can cause a compilation error known as a circular dependency error.

Comment: This will cause a circular Dependency, making the application runt o fail

Comment: Yes, so you need to move Module A to module B

and remove Module B from Module A

Module A don't need to know about moduleB

Comment: I have a need of the the Module B in Module A , hence I added the Module B Dependency in Module A, hence I cant remove it now

Comment: That  will result to an error called circular dependency.

if you need both of them to know about each other, then they need to be in the same module

Comment: or you can have another module called common module which will serve as bridge between them.

Comment: Can you give me some code snippets or any forum to look of adding the two modules under one

Comment: ok ill share a step to solve this

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a `common` module and include it in both `Module A` and `Module B`.

Put the things that both modules require, e.g., interfaces, base classes, and utilities in the common module to avoid a circular dependency.